# Best practice for bulk photo upload on mobile

Tags: mobile-application, image, upload, bulk

I am creating a mobile app app that will require users to upload multiple images. They must take pictures their rental equipment before then after the rental agreement is complete, for proof of damages to the equipment.

I am having trouble finding industry examples of bulk photo uploads, especially on mobile, and en even harder time finding research into best practices.

I attached two wireframe examples of my approach.

Top example:

- icon-style upload button
- image previews next to upload button

Bottom example:

- descriptive upload button with text
- image previews below upload button

Which experience makes the most sense? I lean toward the bottom example but can't communicate why. Hoping for an opinion backed by more expertise

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, it's better to show an icon with an image of a camera and simple text like "Add photos". This will reduce the amount of text needed and be more intuitive for the user as well.
[image]

For the image preview it would be nice for the user to drag and drop to rearrange the order (if that is relevant for your use case). There should also be an option for the user to remove photos if they accidentally selected the wrong photo.

Here are references that might be helpful:

https://medium.com/tripaneer-techblog/a-photo-upload-tool-invent-the-ux-patterns-dont-follow-them-fd0f51188f62

https://medium.com/javarevisited/lets-develop-an-android-app-to-upload-files-and-images-on-cloud-f9670d812060